# JQuery Ui dialog form and partial view reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to open a JQuery Ui dialog form after ajax partial view reload in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Html Code

```
 <div>
    <table id="tabletotal">
      <thead>
        <tr>                    
         <th>
           Operator
         </th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
         @for (int h = 0; h < Model.ToList().Count; h++)
           {
             <tr>
              <td>
                <button  type="button" class="assign"  id="@Model.ElementAt(h).id" >Assign</button>                                    

               </td>
              </tr>
           }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

The dialog form

```
<div id="dialog-form" style="display:none;">
<form action=@Url.Action("Assign", "Ticket") method="post" style="padding-top:10px">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <input id="passedId" name="passedId" type="hidden" />
            <select name="idOperator" id="idOperator" class="form-control">
                @foreach (Model.Data.Operator op in ViewBag.Operators)
                {
                    <option value="@op.id">@op.name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div align="right" style="padding-top:10px">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Send">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS Code

```
$(function () {
    var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 350,
        modal: true
});
$(".assign").button().on("click", function () {
    $('#passedId').val(this.id);
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    //dialog.data("idt", this.id);
    dialog.dialog("open");
});
});
```

I reload this partial view every 3 seconds with Ajax. After the reaload the httppost action ("Assign", "Ticket") fails because the idPassed is null. Which could be the problem? I think that after the reload the id of the button is lost but i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was simple XD

```
$(function () {
    $(".assign").button().on("click", function () {
        $('#passedId').val(this.id);
        createDialog();
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
function createDialog() {
    var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 310,
        width: 350,
        modal: true
    });
}
```